# Lambert W-Function

Tags: terminology, lambert-w

Is there a standard name for the inverse of the Lambert W-Function, in the manner that the name "exponential function" is the name for the inverse function of the logarithmic function.

Comment: The inverse is just $W^{−1}(x)=xe^x$, which isn't really special enough to get a name. I can't say for sure it doesn't have one, but I would be very surprised if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no specific name given to the inverses of any of the special functions, like the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), the [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [$\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), etc., and [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is no exception to the general rule.

Comment: Like $x\log(x)$ is sometimes called a linlogarithmic function, what about linexponential for $xe^x$ ? Other (less serious) suggestion: Trebmal's $M$ function.

Answer (score 1):

Also, be careful when you take an inverse function of $W$ since $W$ has two branches. Probably, you meant the principal branch $W_0$ of it that assumes values from the range $[-1/e,\infty]$. Then, the corresponding inverse function of $W_0$ will be $f(x) = xe^x$ on a domain $x \in [-1, \infty]$.